# What is tapasya? How it is done? Are Samadhi ,Sadhana and Tapasya the same thing?

Tags: practice, meditation

Many asuras , rishis and devtas is said to have performed tapasyas for several hundred years to please and get boons from other gods .Parvati also did tapasya as brahmacharini for several hundred years although she was a human (life span of humans less than 100 years).